# Failed to install the Android studio application on my phone

Tags: android, apk, failed-installation

I am using a Redmi Note 3 phone. I tried launching an android studio application on my phone. I failed showing the error "Session 'app': Error Installing APK". It tried the same with MotoG-4 and it worked. I am working on windows 8. I am not sure if it is because of the compatibility issue(Intel vs Arm architecture). If so, how can I resolve this problem. 
Also, I was able to launch the application before I updated my phone.

Comment: Do you have the proper device drivers? Are you able to detect the device using `adb devices` command?

Comment: The device is detected

Comment: Did you check the compile and target version api of your phone and your app?

Comment: Sometimes, your targeted api could be the culprit. Which os version are you using on your Redmi note 3?

Comment: Android version 6.0.1